# Key code for common characters on international keyboards

Tags: javascript, keyboard

Ok, capturing key codes from special symbols produces different results on keyboards with different layouts. But how about the 'common' characters, like a-z? If you have a QWERTY-keyboard, you'd get key code `81` when you type `q`. When you have an AZERTY-keyboard, do you get code `81` when you press `a`, since `a` is where `q` 'should' be? Or is the mapping done differently?

**EDIT:**

The answer I accepted is probably the best solution when you're capturing keys and want to be sure 'a' is really 'a', but as I explain in the comment underneath that, I still am curious how the key codes are 'translated' when using int'l keyboards. That is: sources suggest at least a-z should be consistent, but I cannot find support for this (or someone who actually tried).

Comment: If you have AZERTY-keyboard then why can't you just try it

Comment: I don't, so I can't. Moreover, this is a simple example, but I suspect there could be more problems with the 'common' alphabetical keys that I can't think of with Russian, Swahili, Ugandan etc. layouts. Hopefully not, of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the `keypress` event rather than `keyup` or `keydown` then the problem goes away because in that event you get character codes rather than key codes.

Example:

```
document.onkeypress = function(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    var charCode = (typeof e.which == "undefined") ? e.keyCode : e.which;
    alert( String.fromCharCode(charCode) );
};
```

And here's the definitive resource on key handling in JavaScript: http://unixpapa.com/js/key.html

Comment: I had found that already, definitely a definite resource, I agree! I actually came to ask this question because of that document, because under 3.3 it lists key codes, and seems to show that 'common' characters, like a-z, return ASCII codes. However, it also states that the codes are converted through the keyboard drivers... A bit puzzling. I guess your solution works best, for it omits influence by keyboard drivers, browsers etc.