# Space key input erases data with regex.replace

Tags: jquery, regex

I searched for a solution for more than three days. I found one stack answer [Stack Ans](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19111723/4425004) and his JSFiddle [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FHf9a/) which is 100% working for Desktop and 99% working for the mobile version.
Sample Code:

```
<input type="text" class="numeric" />
$('.numeric').on('input', function (event) { 
   this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '');
});
```

View the jsfiddle link in mobile and test it for yourself, 
Test case:  provide input value as `12345`, then press `spacebar twice` it `removes 5`, next twice space key `removes 4`. How to solve this?

The below code works in the Desktop browser and not in the mobile browser because the key code is not recognized.

```
$(".numeric").on("keypress", function (event) {
   if ((event.which < 48 || event.which > 57)) event.preventDefault();
});
```

Test Video Log:
[Video Log Bug Report](https://vimeo.com/319472208)

Comment: I tested this out in Android in Chrome browser and didn't get the issue when pressing the space bar.  What mobile browser and phone are you using to test?

Comment: I tested on iOS and didn't got any issue with space...

Comment: @DougF, my phone is Redmi 4, Chrome,  first give number input as 123456789012, then keep on pressing space bar. You will notice the action is causing backspace event. I wish to show you the screen recording got any idea for sharing it with you?

Comment: I tried this again on my phone and I'm not getting the problem you're getting.  When I press space nothing happens.  I can only input numbers into the text box.  I did notice that the JQuery that is referenced is 1.9.x which is pretty old, so maybe you can create a new fiddle with updated JQuery scripts and see if that works.

Comment: @DougF, I tried this with updated jquery version 3.3.1 under w3schools URL(https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=G1J24SFCF8V4), but still the same issue persist. I wish to share my phone screen recording.

Comment: @DougF, Here is my video log for your reference: https://vimeo.com/319472208,

Comment: Is that keyboard that you're using on your phone the default keyboard?  Do you have another browser on your phone to test it out with?  Or even another mobile device?

Comment: Its a google keyboard, my team tester posted a bug for it by testing in Motorolla brand android phone. we cannot change the keyboard here, because it is commonly used among people when it is brought to live.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution to my problem,

```
$('.NumOnly').on('input', function (event) {
if (this.value.indexOf(' ') < 0) {
    this.value = this.value.trim().replace(/[^0-9]/g, '');
    if (!CheckLength(event.target.maxLength, $("#" + event.target.id).val())) {
        event.returnValue = false;
        return false;
    }
}
else this.value = this.value.trim();
});
```

I check the input value has space using `indexOf(' ')`. If the result is >= 0 then `trim()` the value, else `replace` using regular expression based validation.